# Javascript - closure in anonymous function referencing a global function using arguments - how do i use preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, submit, closures

In the following code, where would I use `preventDefault`? I have been testing it to make it work but have not found a good way to cancel the default `submit` action. Which function needs to be capture the event object?

Here is the code:

```
f_name = 'someFunc' ;
f_args(1,2,3) ;

if(element.addEventListener) {
element.addEventListener('submit',(function(name,args,element) {
    return function() {
        window[name].apply(element,args) ;
    }
})(f_name,f_args,element)
,false) ; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f_name = 'someFunc';
f_args = [1, 2, 3];
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener('submit', (function (name, args, element) {
        return function (e) {
            // here 
            e.preventDefault();
            window[name].apply(element, args);
        };
    })(f_name, f_args, element), false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to preventDefault on only some event handlers, you would use `preventDefault()` inside the callback that you use to handle a specific event.  In your example, this would the global function represented by the `name` argument which would be the `someFunc` global function.

If you wanted to do it for all event handlers (which doesn't make a lot of sense to me), then you'd do it in your code right before or after you call `window[name]`.

Comment: Hmm my problem is i was passing in arguments and didnt know how to get the event object when I didnt pass it in as well. In this case I am forming these function calls from a string and when I find return false; im setting up the preventDefault().

Comment: @MagicLasso - Next time, perhaps you could be more specific that all you needed to know was how to get to the event that's passed into the event handler.  That would have been easy for many to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler function will be called with the event as a parameter

```
return function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window[name].apply(element,args) ;
}
```